# Is this possible to get all the variable in property in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

Is there any ways that I can find out how many variable to objective c object have?
For example:

```
@interface myObject:NSObject
{

}
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *firstString;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *secondString;
```

I would like to know that object have `firstString` and `secondString`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Could you clarify?  Are you checking to see if `firstString` and `secondString` have a value? Or...?

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all property names (old-fashioned instance variables need additional code) in `anObject` you can use this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>


u_int           count;
objc_property_t *properties=class_copyPropertyList([anObject class],&count);

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    NSString            *propertyName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];

    NSLog(@"Property: %@",propertyName)
}

free(properties);
```